# Developing an Android Application and Web Application sharing with one database?

Tags: php, android, database

Is there a way to do this? 
I really don't know how to do this. 
Could somebody give me an idea on how to do this? 
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: your android application will send http request to same server. its simple if you have basic of server side scripting.

Comment: Not sure if it can be useful but you can use http://www.parse.com to centralize DB.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible?**

Yes it is.

**How to do it?**

Check this link [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) or this link [there](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html), and there are others floating around on stack as well, hope this guides you in the right path.

Comment: Both links use the deprecated mysql extension.

Comment: Code is easily converted to new `PDO`, but he is pointed in the right direction.